# Scala and util.Iterator[_]

Tags: java, scala, types, interface, typeerror

I am working with a java library in scala, and I need to implement an Interface, which, among other things requires that I implement that I implement Java's `Iterable` interface.

When I try to implement it with or without `JavaConversions` it tells me that the method I am overriding (`iterator(): java.util.Iterator`) is of the wrong type, even though the method is of the type `java.util.Iterator`.

As a side note, could this be because the interface requires that I return an iterator of unspecified type?

Comment: See extempore's (and Daniel Sobral's) answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in the REPL:

```
import java.lang.Iterable
import java.util.Iterator

class A extends Iterable[String] {
    override def iterator(): Iterator[String] = null
}
```

Note that `iterator()` needs to return `Iterator`, not `Iterable`, and that confusingly, `Iterable` is in package `java.lang` while `Iterator` is in `java.util`.

Comment: This is not the problem.
The parent class specifies an **Untyped** iterator, (effectively `Iterator<?>`). If the iterator were typed, I would not have encountered a problem.

For reference the inheritance chain looks like this:


    **Java** interface Iterable -> **Java** interface Component extends Iterable (No Type) -> **Scala** class ScalaComponent extends Component.

Thus, ScalaComponent has `override def iterator(): util.Iterator[_]`. This causes a compiler error.